# Confused About Equation Rearrangment

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, wolfram-alpha

Full disclosure; I have a very very basic understanding of higher math. I apologize if this is stupid / has been answered. I don't really know how to even format my question.

I have a formula used in ray casting off two mirrors. The formula is:
$$
z = \tan (d) (a+b \sec c)
$$
I need to rewrite this equation to solve for $d$.

I have used Wolfram Alpha for this, and it returns:

[Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRG8q.gif)

I don't understand what $n$ is, it wasn't a value in the input. I also don't have the knowledge / skills to rewrite this myself, or any idea of where to start.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is $d$ an angle between $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$?  If so, you don't need the $n$.

Divide both sides by $a+b\sec c$:

$$\frac{z}{a+b\sec c} = \tan d$$

And apply the inverse tangent function.  It satisfies $\tan^{-1}( \tan d) = d$ for all $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$: $$\tan^{-1}(\frac{z}{a+b\sec c}) = d$$ Given the values $z,a,b,c$ there are actually infinitely many numbers $d$ with the property that $\frac{z}{a+b\sec c} = \tan d$.  Indeed, let $$\tan^{-1}(\frac{z}{a+b\sec c})$$ be one such number.  Then $$\tan^{-1}(\frac{z}{a+b\sec c})+\pi$$$$ \tan^{-1}(\frac{z}{a+b\sec c})-\pi$$ $$\tan^{-1}(\frac{z}{a+b\sec c}) - 2\pi $$ $$\tan^{-1}(\frac{z}{a+b\sec c}) + 2\pi$$ and so on are all of the rest of the solutions to that equation.  Usually this is just written as $$\tan^{-1}(\frac{z}{a+b\sec c}) + \pi n$$ where $n$ is an integer, i.e. one of the numbers $\{... -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ... \}$.

Comment: Thank you so much. To follow up, I am not getting the expected number using these values:

arctan(6.6672440169358556 / (0.01 + 10 * sec(0.5235987755982988))) + PI

Wolfram link: [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arctan(6.6672440169358556+%2F+(0.01+%2B+10+*+sec(0.5235987755982988)))+%2B+PI)

Its returning 3.66 radians, whereas the input into tan(0.5235987755982988) (10 sec(0.5235987755982988)) is 0.523.. radians.

Comment: Just don't add $\pi$ and you get back what you started with.

Comment: It works! Thank you once again, this has really been enlightening.

Comment: You're very welcome

Answer (score 0):

As $\tan x = \tan (x + \pi n)$, where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, if you have $\tan d = \frac{z}{a + b\sec c}$ then all values $d$ satisfies this equation are gives by
$$
d = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{z}{a + b\sec c}\right) + \pi n, \quad n\in \mathbb{Z}.
$$